# migration sql 2003 to 2008, Sql side and php side

Tags: sql-server, php

I have a system in php using MSSQL 2003. I need to change the database to MMSQL 2008.

I want to know if there's issue I should look at on

- SQL Side (Query/SP/....)
- PHP Side (Query, connection type, ...)

Answer will be usefull even if it is a "dont worry, using standard connection will work" or "there's not so much depricated function between 2003 and 2008".
If you goth link to other posts answering some of those interrogation or how to see it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MSSQL 2003, so you must mean MSSQL 2005, right? Are you trying to upgrade? Do you have a development environment you can test in? That's your best course of action. Other than that, I'm not sure what you're asking exactly.

But I've upgraded from 2005 to 2008 using a PHP environment before and nothing broke. There might be some deprecated features in 2008 but as far as I know they haven't been removed from the engine, just deprecated. Most everything should work. But again, try it out in a development environment.

Comment: first, your right, it cant be mssql 2003. I'll look when I have rights to the database. I'm sure its on server 2003 but I dont know if its mssql 2005 or 2000. I also already did the migration 2005-2008. I had no problem. If its on 2000, I will re-check online or post another question. Tank you